# I am getting this error, when I'm running my Flutter app

Tags: flutter-layout, flutter-test, jitsi-meet, lib-jitsi-meet

e:  ............/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/jitsi_meet-4.0.0/android/src/main/kotlin/com/gunschu/jitsi_meet/JitsiMeetPlugin.kt: (66, 42): Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':jitsi_meet:compileDebugKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                             13.9s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: I am getting same error !! its been hours . Can anyone response if it gets resolved.

Answer (score 0):

This is related to null safety type, go to the **JitsiMeetPlugin.kt** file and replace **Activity** with null safety **Activity?**.

or use the package with null safety, *https://pub.dev/packages/jitsi_meet/versions/4.0.0-nullsafety.0*